# ORA-00936: missing expression. Adding constraint to subtype in oracle apex

Tags: database, oracle, constraints

alter table "PHYSICIAN" add constraint
"PHYSICIAN_CON" check ( "STAFF_NO" IN Select STAFF_NO From STAFF Where POSITION='PHYSICIAN')
/

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have a subquery within a `CHECK` constraint.  It's simply not supported by Oracle.

From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm#sthref2913):

> Conditions of check constraints cannot contain the following constructs:
>
> - Subqueries and scalar subquery expressions

I'm afraid that there's no constraint you can use to enforce your condition, unless you have a table somewhere that contains only the physicians.  However, I suspect that if you did have such a table, you'd probably have already figured out it would be a better idea to create a FK constraint to that table instead.